# Error 255 while init h2o server with Java 8 + Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, java-8, h2o

I am using `h2o` on Python 3.6.5 and try to call `h2o.init(port=54617)` inside a Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu Bash (Windows 10).

I installed Open-JDK-8.

However, I have the error of 255 https://pastebin.com/Zb621fps

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54617..... not found.
    Attempting to start a local H2O server...
      Java Version: openjdk version "1.8.0_171"; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11); OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
      Starting server from /home/user/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar
      Ice root: /tmp/tmp43tw2ak8
      JVM stdout: /tmp/tmp43tw2ak8/h2o_user_started_from_python.out
      JVM stderr: /tmp/tmp43tw2ak8/h2o_user_started_from_python.err
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    H2OConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in init(url, ip, port, https, insecure, username, password, cookies, proxy, start_h2o, nthreads, ice_root, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, strict_version_check, ignore_config, extra_classpath, **kwargs)
        251                                      _msgs=("Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at {url}",
    --> 252                                             "connected.", "not found."))
        253     except H2OConnectionError:

    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in open(server, url, ip, port, https, auth, verify_ssl_certificates, proxy, cookies, verbose, _msgs)
        317             conn._timeout = 3.0
    --> 318             conn._cluster = conn._test_connection(retries, messages=_msgs)
        319             # If a server is unable to respond within 1s, it should be considered a bug. However we disable this

    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py in _test_connection(self, max_retries, messages)
        587             raise H2OConnectionError("Could not establish link to the H2O cloud %s after %d retries\n%s"
    --> 588                                      % (self._base_url, max_retries, "\n".join(errors)))
        589 

    H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://localhost:54617 after 5 retries
    [39:11.07] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54617): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c4c69e198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
    [39:12.28] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54617): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c519308d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
    [39:13.48] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54617): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c51bc4438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
    [39:14.69] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54617): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c51bc4978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
    [39:15.89] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54617): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2c51930dd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    H2OServerError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-29-db4aa26775ed> in <module>()
    ----> 2 h2o.init(port = 54617)

    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in init(url, ip, port, https, insecure, username, password, cookies, proxy, start_h2o, nthreads, ice_root, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, strict_version_check, ignore_config, extra_classpath, **kwargs)
        259             raise H2OConnectionError('Can only start H2O launcher if IP address is localhost.')
        260         hs = H2OLocalServer.start(nthreads=nthreads, enable_assertions=enable_assertions, max_mem_size=mmax,
    --> 261                                   min_mem_size=mmin, ice_root=ice_root, port=port, extra_classpath=extra_classpath)
        262         h2oconn = H2OConnection.open(server=hs, https=https, verify_ssl_certificates=not insecure,
        263                                      auth=auth, proxy=proxy,cookies=cookies, verbose=True)

    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py in start(jar_path, nthreads, enable_assertions, max_mem_size, min_mem_size, ice_root, port, extra_classpath, verbose)
        119         if verbose: print("Attempting to start a local H2O server...")
        120         hs._launch_server(port=port, baseport=baseport, nthreads=int(nthreads), ea=enable_assertions,
    --> 121                           mmax=max_mem_size, mmin=min_mem_size)
        122         if verbose: print("  Server is running at %s://%s:%d" % (hs.scheme, hs.ip, hs.port))
        123         atexit.register(lambda: hs.shutdown())

    ~/anaconda3/envs/barco3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py in _launch_server(self, port, baseport, mmax, mmin, ea, nthreads)
        315         while True:
        316             if proc.poll() is not None:
    --> 317                 raise H2OServerError("Server process terminated with error code %d" % proc.returncode)
        318             ret = self._get_server_info_from_logs()
        319             if ret:

    H2OServerError: Server process terminated with error code 255
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Look at the JVM stdout and JVM stderr files pointed at by the output you pasted.